# Разбор строки регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите подобрать регулярное выражение. Имеется строка

```
  nani?  type: 0 { 1,2,3,4,5 } sometext type: 1 { 6,7,8,9,10 } balabla type: 2 { 11,12,13,14,15 } //more text...
```

Необходимо распарсить её таким образом:

```
1. 0 { 1,2,3,4,5 }
2. 1 { 6,7,8,9,10 }
3. 2 { 11,12,13,14,15 }

/^type: [0-9] (.*)$/ работает не так как мне надо :D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
$res='nani?  type: 0 { 1,2,3,4,5 } sometext type: 1 { 6,7,8,9,10 } balabla type: 2 { 11,12,13,14,15 } //more text...';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]+[ ]*{.*?}/', $res, $arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Результат

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "0 { 1,2,3,4,5 }" [1]=> string(16) "1 { 6,7,8,9,10 }" [2]=> string(20) "2 { 11,12,13,14,15 }" } }
```

Comment: Спасибо - работает

А из такого 0: Физическая атака;
 1: Максимальная физическая атака;
 2: Физическая атака(%);
 3: Магическая атака ;
 как выдрать то что между : и ;

Comment: .  
    
    /:.*?;/

Comment: Спасибо, и последний вопрос, как выдрать отсюда
текст по номеру
т.е 0 => Физическая атака

Comment: Смотрите внимательно результат следующего кода- у цифр будет индекс 1, у слов индекс 2.
    
    header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $res='А из такого 0: Физическая атака; 1: Максимальная физическая атака; 2: Физическая атака(%); 3: Магическая атака ;';
    preg_match_all('/([0-9]+):(.*?);/', $res, $arr);
    var_dump($arr);

Comment: так я сделал, работает, мне бы именно по конкретному символу аля - /(15):(.*?);/ - так не работает

вернее работает, но может вывести как 15 так и 150

Comment: @kenpachi приведите пример, где может вывести как 15 так и 150.